# Sample Bottle App (Python) gives 404 even though route is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

I am just getting started with Bottle. I have found a sample app on [GitHub](https://github.com/saipraveen-a/bottle-example). The sample just has a server.py file which looks like below

```
import bottle

APP = bottle.Bottle()

@APP.get('/')
def index():
  return '<p>Hello</p>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  bottle.run(application=APP)
```

The requirements.txt file has

```
bottle
gunicorn
```

as dependencies. I am using Python 3.7.2. After running pip install -r requirements.txt, I ran python server.py. The server starts up without error on Port 8080

```
Bottle v0.12.18 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer(application=<bottle.Bottle object at 0x1040fa2d0>))...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

When I access http://localhost:8080, I get

```
Error: 404 Not Found
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/' caused an error:

Not found: '/'
```

Please let me know what's wrong with the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace bottle.run(application=APP) application arg name to app
`bottle.run(app=APP)`

Comment: I am able to run the app using python server.py. How can i run this using gunicorn?. gunicorn -w 2 server:app doesnt work for me. Please let me know

Comment: Failed to find application object 'application' in 'server'. This is the error I am getting

Comment: use `bottle.run(app=APP,server="gunicorn",workers=2)`

Comment: Is it possible to start the server without modifying the app?